# What are the rules in the Golden Shoe award in cases when the player transfers to a league with a different cycle?

Tags: football

Most of the European football leagues are played from autumn to spring, but there are a few exceptions, such as [Belarusian Premier League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarusian_Premier_League), [Faroe Islands Premier League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faroe_Islands_Premier_League), Finnish [Veikkausliiga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veikkausliiga), Norwegian [Eliteserien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliteserien), Swedish [Allsvenskan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allsvenskan).
See also: [Domestic association football season § League season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_association_football_season#League_seasons).

The [European Golden Shoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Golden_Shoe) is an award for the top goalscorer among the players from European leagues. Naturally, it is necessary to deal somehow with the fact that players in nordic leagues have a different season.
For example, European Golden Shoe rankings [from December 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=European_Golden_Shoe&oldid=1130762869#2022%E2%80%9323_season_standings) show 25 goals from [2022 Eliteserien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Eliteserien) for [Amahl Pellegrino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amahl_Pellegrino); for players from competitions such as Bundesliga, Ligue 1, Premier League, etc., the goals from 2022-23 seasons are counted.
Similarly, in the current (2023-24) season, the goals scored in the 2023 season will be counted for players from Nordic leagues.

However, an interesting situation happened recently with [Akor Adams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akor_Adams) who scored 15 goals in [2023 Eliteserien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Eliteserien#Season_statistics) for Lillestrøm. He now plays for Montpellier in Ligue 1 and he scored 7 goals in the [2023–24 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023%E2%80%9324_Ligue_1#Season_statistics) so far.
Actually, you can see those goals added in the [current revision of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=European_Golden_Shoe&oldid=1185263252#2023%E2%80%9324_season_standings) - naturally, Wikipedia is definitely not an official source.
Back in the [2021–22 season](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=European_Golden_Shoe&oldid=1085446637#2021%E2%80%9322_season_standings) there was a footnote (about the goals scored by [Ohi Omoijuanfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohi_Omoijuanfo)) saying that: "In the case that a player scores in both summer and winter leagues, those points totals are not combined." But no reference was included there.

What do rules of the European Golden Shoe say about cases like this?

Answer (score 2):

According to different websites/organisations/media, only the points from the first club are counted (I've selected French sources because the original award was created by the French and many sources in that language are available):

> **translated**: Players transferred during the year to a different type of championship only retain the points acquired with the first club.
>
> **original**: Les joueurs transférés en cours d'année dans un championnat de type différent ne conservent que les points acquis avec le premier club.

For instance, the Wikipedia article in English doesn't mention the evolution of the rules like the French one does:  [Règlement à partir de 1997 -- rules and regulation since 1997](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soulier_d%27or_europ%C3%A9en) and [another source here](http://www.eurotopteam.com/football/soulierdor.php)

From "*The ESM Golden Shoe will be shared for only the second time*" ([UEFA.com](https://www.uefa.com/news/0215-0e8adf330815-9bf564f4e571-1000--ronaldo-and-suarez-share-golden-shoe-accolade/)):

> A player cannot play first in a summer league (e.g. Norway) and then in a winter league (e.g. Spain) and combine the points totals for each season.

Comment: On the talk page [of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:European_Golden_Shoe), this source in English is mentioned: [Ronaldo and Suárez share Golden Shoe accolade](https://www.uefa.com/news/0215-0e8adf330815-9bf564f4e571-1000--ronaldo-and-suarez-share-golden-shoe-accolade/) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20221005060402/https://www.uefa.com/news/0215-0e8adf330815-9bf564f4e571-1000--ronaldo-and-suarez-share-golden-shoe-accolade/)).
Just in case you want add that to the answer, too.

Comment: But it only mentions this issue briefly at the end: "A player cannot play first in a summer league (e.g. Norway) and then in a winter league (e.g. Spain) and combine the points totals for each season."

Comment: @Martin: if you think it adds value, I've edited ;)